# How to set counter value in the application laucher icon in Oreo?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo, appicon

In my Android app I need to show the counter on launcher app icon.

Before Android Oreo I used ShortcutBager library. But this one doesn't work anymore in the newer Android versions.

As far as I understand, native Android Oreo bagdes are showing only when app receives notifications. Is there any way to set the counter value manually?